# Array of vectors and variable array

Tags: c++

Could anyone please help me? I was doing [a problem on HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/variable-sized-arrays/problem) and there was this problem using vectors. But I am getting segmentation faults.

What changes do I need to make in this code to get the desired results?

Here's my code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n,q;
    cin>>n>>q;

    vector<int> var[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int size;
        cin>>size;
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
        {
            int elm;
            cin>>elm;
            var[n].insert(var[n].begin(),elm);
            var[n].begin()++;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<q;i++)
    {
        int vindex,index;
        cin>>vindex>>index;
        cout<<var[vindex][index]<<"\n";
    }  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/variable-sized-arrays/problem

Comment: `var[n].insert(var[n].begin(),elm);`. Do you mean `var[i]`?, because `var[n]` is already out of bounds.

Comment: Did you check how big the array is? Perhaps it overflows the stack.

Comment: Did you check the documentation of the compiler whether it supports VLA for non-trivial types?

Comment: Also I don't understand what are you trying to do with `var[n].insert(var[n].begin(),elm); var[n].begin()++;`. According to the problem I think you want `var[i].push_back(elem);`

Comment: I added the link to your question. Actually the question should be selfcontained and have a summary of what the code is supposed to do. In particular it would be good if you explain why you need a c-array of vectors and what are the "desired results"

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` *is* C++'s variable sized array.

`var[n]` is beyond the end of `var`, you presumably meant to use the ith `std::vector<int>`.

We can clean it up further by noting that we are *copying* values

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    int n;
    int q;
    std::cin >> n >> q;

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> var(n);
    for(auto & vec : var)
    {
        int size;
        std::cin >> size;
        vec.resize(size);

        std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), size, vec.begin());
    }

    for(int i=0; i < q; ++i)
    {
        int row, col;
        std::cin >> row >> col;
        std::cout << var[row][col] << '\n';

    }  

    return 0;
}
```